# Exclude route from Laravel authentication

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

After running `php artisan make:auth` all the required routes are in the `route.php` file, but is it possible to remove one (I want to remove the register route)?

Currently I have

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();
});
```

I know that `Route::auth()` is a shortcut to add all the routes.
Should I specify the routes myself instead of using the shortcut?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't exclude register with the current implementation of [`Route::auth()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L346).

You would have to specify all the routes manually so

```
// Authentication Routes...
$this->get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
$this->post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
$this->get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');

// Password Reset Routes...
$this->get('password/reset/{token?}', 'Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm');
$this->post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
$this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@reset');
```

I think this is a fairly common thing to want to do it would be nice if there was a parameter to the `auth` method to say without register maybe you could submit a pull-request to the project.

Comment: Note: This works for Laravel <= 7 versions, if you have newest Laravel versions you should change the definition routes syntax, check refs

Answer (score 6):

In the new releases you can do it like so (in your web.php file):

```
Auth::routes(['register'=>false]);
```

Answer (score 1):

As Mark Davidson said, it's not possible out of the box. But this is how I have handled.

Now it might be overkill, but I pass along an array of what is needed. If no parameters are passed, then default routes are created.

```
// Include the authentication and password routes
Route::auth(['authentication', 'password']);
```

```
/**
 * Register the typical authentication routes for an application.
 *
 * @param array $options
 * @return void
 */
public function auth(array $options = [])
{
    if ($options) {
        // Authentication Routes...
        if (in_array('authentication', $options)) {
            $this->get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
            $this->post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
            $this->get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');
        }

        // Registration Routes...
        if (in_array('registration', $options)) {
            $this->get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
            $this->post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@register');
        }

        // Password Reset Routes...
        if (in_array('password', $options)) {
            $this->get('password/reset/{token?}', 'Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm');
            $this->post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
            $this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@reset');
        }
    } else {
        // Authentication Routes...
        $this->get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
        $this->post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
        $this->get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');

        // Registration Routes...
        $this->get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
        $this->post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@register');

        // Password Reset Routes...
        $this->get('password/reset/{token?}', 'Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm');
        $this->post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
        $this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@reset');
    }
}
```

For your case, you can probably just pass a `boolean` as parameter instead of an `array`. If the boolean is `true` then do not load the `register` routes, otherwise load everything.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I just YOLO and change this in the RegisterController.php

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}
```

to this

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

This makes the register page require you to be loged in to reach it.

It's a hack. But it is a good hack.

EDIT:
and just add this to your seeder to make life easier:

```
    $u1= new App\User;
    $u1->name = 'Your name';
    $u1->email = 'your@mail.com';
    $u1->password = bcrypt('yourPassword');
    $u1->save();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add a redirect to the /register route like so:

```
<?php

Auth::routes();

// prevent registration, this needs to be after Auth::routes()
Route::redirect('register', '/home', 301);
```